# Migrated manifestV2 to V3 after that chrome.action.onClicked.addListener not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

While migrating from manifest v2 to v3 facing issue(`chrome.action.onClicked.addListener` not working/invoking).

I have a manifest.json defined like this

```
{ 
"name": "dummy",
"manifest_version": 3,
"version": "5.2.0",
"version_name": "5.2.0",
"description": "The dummy v5.2.0  plugin allows our users to gain instant access to 
their metadata and data.",
"action": {
 "default_title": "execute.js will run (watch the Chrome DevTools' console)"
},
"content_scripts": [
 {
  "js": ["content.js"],
  "matches": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
 ],
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "tabs",
  "scripting",
  "storage"
],
"host_permissions": [
  "https://*/*",
  "http://*/*"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [{
   "resources": ["*.html"],
   "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"]}]}
```

and `background.js` file has this code

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
     chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    setDomain({ tab: tabs[0] });
 });});
```

I'm really lost here and it's extremely hard to debug.This code was working before migrating to manifest v3.

Comment: Do you see an error message? If so, it helps to include it in the question.

Comment: Remove chrome.tabs.query line and simply call `setDomain({ tab });` Note that there are bugs in Chrome that make the service worker nonfunctional: try adding `self.oninstall=()=>skipWaiting()` at the beginning of the background script.

Answer (score 0):

(I will edit this answer once the OP has given us more information)

I have created a test extension with

- your manifest.json
- your background.js, with `setDomain({ tab: tabs[0] });` replaced with `console.log("setDomain({ tab: tabs[0] });");`
- a content.js that only contains the code `console.log("content.js");`

When I click the action in my test extension, it excutes the code `console.log("setDomain({ tab: tabs[0] });");`

In other words: The code you have shown us is not enough to diagnose your problem.

We can only help you if you do the following:

Please upload your extension's entire source code to Github or a similar website.

If you don't want to upload your extension's entire source code:

Please create a simplified version of your extension that reproducibly demonstrates your problem.
Then upload the simplified extension's entire source code to Github or a similar website.

Comment: Please find the boilerplate source code link.This code is working  fine for the  first time  when we clicked on extension. On the next attempts to click it is not working. Please  let us know if you have solution  @Thomas



https://github.com/shaikshahina/chromeextension